# Parsing Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Bit lost while parsing the hash, actually i want to retrieve the id for `"HTTP get traffic"` which is in this case `9`.? can anyone help?

```
gettest = {
  "Groups" => [
    {
      "GroupName" => {"TextId" => "Hardware"},
      "Tests" => [
        {"Description"=>{"TextId"=>"ODU current measurement"}, "Id" => 0}
      ]
    },
    {
      "GroupName"=>{"TextId"=>"LAN"},
      "Tests" => [
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Ethernet status"}, "Id" => 2},
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Number of TCP Sessions"}, "Id" => 3}
      ]
    },
    {
      "GroupName" => {"TextId" => "Satellite connection"},
      "Tests" => [
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Physical layer status"}, "Id" => 4},
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Data link layer status"}, "Id" => 5},
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Network layer status"}, "Id" => 6}
      ]
    },
    {
      "GroupName" => {"TextId" => "Software"},
      "Tests" => [
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Software"}, "Id" => 1}
      ]
    },
    {
      "GroupName" => {"TextId" => "Traffic"},
      "Tests" => [
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "Ping traffic"}, "Id" => 7},
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "DNS traffic"}, "Id" => 8},
        {"Description" => {"TextId" => "HTTP get traffic"}, "Id" => 9}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Will the structure of the groups and the nesting always be the same? Or would it be possible that the structure is very different and you need to deep search the whole structure if there is even any "HTTP get traffic" in any of the groups?

Comment: yes it will be always same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anything like this?

```
traffic_group = gettest['Groups'].find do |group|
  group['GroupName']['TextId'] == 'Traffic'
end
if traffic_group 
  http_get_traffic = traffic_group['Tests'].find do |test| 
    test['Description']['TextId'] == 'HTTP get traffic' 
  end
  if http_get_traffic
    http_get_traffic_id = http_get_traffic['Id']
    puts "HTTP get traffic id: #{http_get_traffic_id}"
  else
    puts 'no http get traffic node found'
  end
else
  puts 'no traffic group found'
end
```

Comment: I am getting an error, i edited the post what i am receiving in gettest,,, can you please have a look

Comment: try now man, updated

Comment: Receiving the following error      : Traceback (most recent call last):
main.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: man, if I copy your code and then mine I have the right response.

Comment: you changed something else